# what is the square root of 144

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am preparing for GRE and can anybody explain this to me

What is $\sqrt{144}$.

Why is the answer not $12 , -12. $

The calculator gives 12. does it mean -12 is incorrect?

Comment: By definition, the square root must be non-negative.

Comment: If you are solving something like $x^2=144$, make sure to use the absolute value sign when extracting the radical, i.e., $|x|=12\iff x=\pm12$.

Comment: This is more memorization of a definition than an actual issue. However the comments/answers here explain several nuances.

Answer (score 9):

While -12 is "a square root" of 144, the square root operation here denotes a function from nonnegative real numbers to nonnegative real numbers.  A function can only produce a single result.  So the expresion $\sqrt{144}$ evaluates to the positive root 12.

We refer to this convention by saying $\sqrt{x}$ is the *principal* square root of $x \ge 0$.  See [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root) for more background.

Answer (score 7):

$144$ has two roots, yes: $\pm 12$. So $-12$ is a root of $144$.

However, we define the principal square root of $\sqrt {x^2} = |x|$, so in your case, $$\sqrt{144} = \sqrt{12^2} = |12| = 12$$

And your calculator is designed to return the principal square root. See [Wolfram Alpha for the distinction](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28144%29): $12$ is the principal square root (what we mean by $\sqrt x$, given $x\geq 0$), and $-12$ is considered a real root.

Comment: Needs another TU +1